# Creando script en windows(batch) para que me ejecute xamp ( servicio apache y mysql) en segundo plano

Tags: windows, batch, .bat

estoy haciendo un pequeño script para windows, que me ejecute estos dos comandos, básicamente ejecuta los servicios de XAMP : apache y mysql. El problema es que abre una consola en la que ejecuta ambos servicios y no la cierra, y en el caso de que cierre manualmente estas terminan los servicios.

**¿Cómo podría hacer para que ejecutara ambos servicios en background?**

```
    :Ejecuto XAMP (Apache y MySQL)
    set root=c:\xampp\
    :MySQL
    start %root%mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=%root%mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
    :Apache
    start /b "" %root%apache\bin\httpd.exe
```

Comment: Probaste a poner `EXIT` al final del script?